# Mostrar un valor determinado en un campo select

Tags: javascript, css, html5

estoy con un proyecto en JavaScript, HTML y CSS, y me encuentro con un problema a la hora de mostrar los datos para actualizar. Os comento, tengo un formulario para crear Ejercicios con los campos (nombre, texto, respuestas y dificultad), este último es un select con las opciones (Fácil, Media, Alta). A continuación, quiero hacer un formulario para actualizar los ejercicios, y quiero mostrar los campos que se han guardado previamente al crear el ejercicio, campos que recupero de la base de datos. El problema es a la hora de mostrar el campo dificultad del select, es decir, por ejemplo, si cree un ejercicio con dificultad Media, a la hora de mostrar el formulario de actualización de dicho ejercicio, que el select esté marcado con la opción dificultad Media. Os adjunto aquí el código por si tenéis alguna sugerencia.

```
function mostrarActualizacionEjercicio(nombre,texto,respuesta,dificultad){
  if ($.cookie("pro")){

    var cadena = '<div id="formActualizarEjercicioImg" class="thumbnail" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:10px; width:80%;align-items: center;">';
    cadena=cadena+'<div id="formActualizarEjercicio" class="caption" align="center">';
    cadena=cadena+'<p id="textActualizarEjercicio" style="font-size:2em;color:green"><b>Actualizar Ejercicios</b></p>';
    cadena=cadena+'<label for="nombreEjercicio">Nombre Ejercicio: </label><input id="nombreEjercicio" type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" value="'+nombre+'" style="margin-bottom:5px;" disabled>';
    cadena=cadena+'<label for="textoEjercicio">Texto Ejercicio: </label><textarea id="textoEjercicio" name="TextoEjercicio" rows="10" cols="40">'+texto+'</textarea>';
    cadena=cadena+'<label for="respuestaEjercicio">Respuesta Ejercicio: </label><input id="respuestaEjercicio" type="text" class="form-control" name="respuesta" value="'+respuesta+'" style="margin-bottom:5px;">';

    //Select dificultad
    cadena=cadena+'<label for="dificultadEjercicio">Dificultad: </label><select class="form-control" id="dificultadEjercicio" name="dificultadEjercicio">';
    cadena=cadena+'<option value="" selected="selected"></option><option value="Fácil">Fácil</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option></select></div>';
    cadena=cadena+'<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalInstrucciones">Instrucciones</button>'
    cadena=cadena+'<button type="button" id="verEjercicioBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Ver ejercicio</button>';
    cadena=cadena+'</div></div>';

    $('#inicio').append(cadena);

    $('#verEjercicioBtn').on('click',function(){
      var nombreEjercicio=$('#nombreEjercicio').val();
      if(nombreEjercicio==""){
        $('#campoNombre').remove();
        //var cadena='<p style="color:red;">Rellena el campo nombre</p>';
        mostrarAviso("#formActualizarEjercicioImg","<p id='campoNombre' style='color:red;font-size:1.5em;'>Rellena el campo nombre</p>");
      }
      else{
        $('#campoNombre').remove();
        var textoEjercicio=$('#textoEjercicio').val();

        if($('#textoEjercicio').val().length<1){
          $('#campoTexto').remove();
          //var cadena='<p style="color:red;">Rellena el campo texto</p>';
          mostrarAviso("#formActualizarEjercicioImg","<p id='campoTexto' style='color:red;font-size:1.5em;'>Rellena el campo texto</p>");
        }
        else{
          var nRespuestas=textoEjercicio.split("@");
          $('#campoTexto').remove();
          var respuestaEjercicio=$('#respuestaEjercicio').val();
          var respuestasEjercicioSeparado= respuestaEjercicio.split(" ");
          if(respuestasEjercicioSeparado.length!=nRespuestas.length-1){
            $('#campoRespuesta').remove();
            //var cadena='<p style="color:red;">Rellena el campo respuesta correctamente</p>';  
            mostrarAviso("#formActualizarEjercicioImg","<p id='campoRespuesta' style='color:red;font-size:1.5em;'>Has puesto "+respuestasEjercicioSeparado.length+" respuestas </p>");
          }
          else{    
            $('#campoRespuesta').remove();
            $('#campoDificultad').remove();
            var dificultadEjercicio=$('#dificultadEjercicio').val();
            if(dificultadEjercicio==""){
              mostrarAviso("#formActualizarEjercicioImg","<p id='campoDificultad' style='color:red;font-size:1.5em;'>Rellena el campo dificultad</p>");
            }
            else{
              $('#mostrarConsultas').remove();
              mostrarDatosProfesor(nombreEjercicio);
              mostrarHuecos(textoEjercicio);
              mostrarSolucion(nombreEjercicio, textoEjercicio, respuestaEjercicio,dificultadEjercicio);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Esta es la función que llama a la anterior:

```
function mostrarTablaEjercicios(datos){

  if ($.cookie("pro")){
    var cadena ='<div id="tablaEjercicios" class="container"><h2>Listado de ejercicios profesor</h2><p>Ejercicios presentes en la base de datos creados por ti <button type="button" id="crearEjerBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-responsive btninter right" style="margin-left:30px" >Crear ejercicio</button> </p>';
    cadena = cadena + '<table class="table table-striped" id="tab"><thead><tr class="w3-red">';
    cadena = cadena + '<th>Nombre Ejercicio</th><th>Profesor</th><th>Dificultad</th><th>Acciones</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

    for(var i=0;i<datos.length;i++){
       cadena = cadena + '<tr><td>'+datos[i].nombre+'</td><td>'+datos[i].emailProfesor+'</td><td>'+datos[i].dificultad+'</td>';

       cadena = cadena + ' <td><a href="#" id="editar" class="ejemplo-pencil" data-datos-nombre="'+datos[i].nombre+'" data-datos-texto="'+datos[i].texto+'" data-datos-respuesta="'+datos[i].respuesta+'" data-datos-dificultad="'+datos[i].dificultad+'">';
       cadena=cadena+'<img id="pencil" src="cliente/img/pencil.png" style="width:6%; margin-left: 10px;"></a></td></tr> ';
     }

  cadena = cadena + '</tbody></table>';
  cadena = cadena + '<button type="button" id="mostrarTodosBtn" class="btn btn-link">Ver todos</button> </div>';

  $('#tablas').append(cadena);

  $('.ejemplo-pencil').on('click',function(){
    var nombre = $(this).data('datos-nombre');
    var texto = $(this).data('datos-texto');
    var respuesta = $(this).data('datos-respuesta');
    var dificultad = $(this).data('data-datos-dificultad');

    mostrarActualizacionEjercicio(nombre,texto,respuesta,dificultad);
  });
```

}

}

[image: Imagen]

Sería mostrar "Media" o el valor correspondiente en el campo select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estoy seguro de entenderlo. Quizá te refieras a esto. Debajo de `$('#inicio').append(cadena);` prueba a poner esto:

`$('#dificultadEjercicio').val(dificultad);`

Suponinendo que `dificultad` tenga el valor de la dificultad que quieres poner. Osea, si `dificultad = 'Media'`, entonces te pondrá el select en "Media". Prueba con `$('#dificultadEjercicio').val("Media");` o "Fácil", para probar si quieres.

Esto te pondrá el select con id `dificultadEjercicio` al valor de la variable `dificultad`.

En la función que llama a `mostrarActualizacionEjercicio`, cambia `var dificultad = $(this).data('data-datos-dificultad');` por `var dificultad = $(this).data('datos-dificultad');`

Por darte *feedback* del resto del código, está bastante desordenado. Deberías separar los códigos HTML, CSS y JavaScript en archivos separados. Al tenerlo todo junto está bastante desordenado y es difícil de leer. Toda esa variable `cadena` debería estar en un archivo HTML, no en JavaScript, y dentro de `cadena` todos (o casi) los atributos en los `style` de las etiquetas deberían estar en un archivo CSS.

Por otro lado, deberías dar espacio a tu código para que respire. Más saltos de línea, más espacios, así se ve todo muy pegado y es más difícil de leer.

Veo en todos los `if-else` que haces `remove()` de algún elemento tanto en el `if` como en el `else`, en lugar de eso, ponlo antes del `if-else`.

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por responder, respecto de la respuesta que me has dado, he probado y no me funciona, voy actualizar la pregunta para referirme bien a lo que digo. En los otros comentarios, es cierto que esta desordenado, tengo que reajustarlo como dices. Muchas gracias por responder

Comment: Cuál es el valor de la variable `dificultad`? Si es "Media", "Fácil" o "Alta", debería funcionar. ¿Si pones `$('#dificultadEjercicio').val("Media");` te lo pone en media, verdad?

Comment: Sí, lo acabo de probar como me has dicho, y funciona si pongo media. Sin embargo con dificultad no funciona, el valor lo recojo en otra función y lo paso como parámetro, y el valor es uno de los 3

Comment: He actualizado con el código de la función que llama al formulario de actualizar

Comment: @VíctorRubénGómezGarcía esta línea `var dificultad = $(this).data('data-datos-dificultad');` debería ser así: `var dificultad = $(this).data('datos-dificultad');`. Te sobra `data-`.

Comment: En efecto, era ese error. Muchas gracias y te haré caso y ordenaré el código para que no ocurran estas cosas. Ya funciona como dijiste al principio.Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si estás usando jQuery, puedes usar el método `.val()`, como con cualquier `input`

```js
setTimeout(()=> $("#dificultad").val("3"), 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dificultad">
  <option value="1">Facil</option>
  <option value="2">Medio</option>
  <option value="3">Difícil</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Eso es lo que quiero exactamente, sin embargo he probado `setTimeout(()=> $("#dificultadEjercicio").val(dificultad), 2000);`, pero me muestra siempre la primera opción "Fácil"

Comment: La función setTimeout la he añadido para que se vea el cambio tras dos segundos, sólo necesitas `$("#dificultadEjercicio").val(dificultad)`

Comment: Sí si, lo sé, pero aún poniendo eso, si por ejemplo recupero un ejercicio con dificultad "Media", me muestra dificultad "Fácil"